# perl: strip html tags, manipulate text, and then return html tags to their original positions

Tags: html, perl, nlp, strip

I'm using the Html::Strip module to remove all html tags from a file. I want to then manipulate the resulting text (stripped of html) and finally return the html tags to their original positions.

The text manipulation I'm doing requires breaking the text into arrays using split(/ /, $text). I then do some natural language processing of the resulting arrays (including adding *new* html tags to some key words). Once I'm finished processing the text, I'd like to return the original tags to their places while keeping the text manipulations I've done in the meantime intact.

I would be satisfied if I could simply remove all whitespace from within the original tags (since whitespace within tags is ignored by browsers). That way my NLProcessing could simply ignore words that are tags (contain '<' or '>').

I've tried diving into the guts of Html::Strip (in an effort to modify it to my needs), but I can't understand what the following piece of code does:

```
  my $stripped = $self->strip_html( $text );
  if( $self->decode_entities && $_html_entities_p ) {
    $stripped = HTML::Entities::decode($stripped);
  }
```

Seems like strip_html is a sub, but I can't find that sub anywhere.

Anyway thanks for any and all advice.

---

... the next day...

After a bit of back and forth with @amon, I have come up with a solution that I believe is sufficient for my purposes. amon pushed me in the right direction even though he recommended I not do what I've done anyway, haha.

It is a brutish method, but gets the job done satisfactorily. Gonna leave it here in the off chance that someone else has the same wishes as me and doesn't mind a quick and dirty solution:

```
my $input = text.html;
my $stripped = $hs->parse($input);
$hs->eof;
```

so now I have two string variables. One is the html file I want to manipulate, and the other is the same file stripped of html.

```
my @marks = split(/\s/, $stripped);
@marks = uniq(@marks);
```

Now I have a list of all non-HTMLtag-associated words that appear in my file.

```
$input = HTML::Entities::decode($input);
$input =~ s/\</ \</g; 
$input =~ s/\>/\> /g; 
$input =~ s/\n/ \n /g; 
$input =~ s/\r/ \r /g; 
$input =~ s/\t/ \t /g;
```

Now I've decoded my HTML containing var and have ensured that no word is up against a "<", or ">" or non-space whitespace character.

```
foreach my $mark(@marks) { $input =~ s/ \Q$mark\E / TAQ\+$mark\TAQ /g; }
$input =~ s/TAQ\+TAQ//g;
```

Now I've "tagged" each word with a "+" and have separated words from non-words with the TAQ delimiter. I can now split on TAQ and ignore any item that does not contain a "+" when performing my NLP and text manipulation. Once I'm done, I rejoin and strip all of the "+". Follow that with some clever encoding, remove all the extra spaces I inserted, and *BAM!* I've now got my NLProcessing completed, have manipulated the text, and still have all of my HTML in the right places.

There are a lot of caveats here, and I'm not going to go into all of them. Most problematic is the need to decode and then encode, coupled with the fact that HTML::Strip doesn't always strip all the javascript or invalid HTML. There are ways to work around that, but again I don't have room or time to discuss that here.

Thanks amon for your help, and I welcome any criticism or suggestions. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

The module `HTML::Strip` uses the XS glue language to connect the Perl code with C code. You can find the [XS file](https://metacpan.org/source/KILINRAX/HTML-Strip-1.06/Strip.xs) e.g. on (meta-)cpan. It includes a file [strip_html.c](https://metacpan.org/source/KILINRAX/HTML-Strip-1.06/strip_html.c) that implements the actual algorithm. Due to the definitions in the XS file, a `strip_html` sub is available in the Perl code as part of the `HTML::Strip` package. Therefore, it can be invoked as a method on an appropriate object.

#### Explanation of that piece of code

```
my $stripped = $self->strip_html( $text );
```

This will invoke the C function on the contents of `$text` to strip all the HTML tags. The stripped data will then be assigned to `$stripped`.

```
if( $self->decode_entities && $_html_entities_p ) {
  $stripped = HTML::Entities::decode($stripped);
}
```

Suffixing variable names with `-p` is a [lispish tradition](http://catb.org/jargon/html/p-convention.html) to indicate boolean variables (or *predicates*, in mathematics). Here, it indicates if `HTML::Entities` could be loaded: `my $_html_entities_p = eval 'require HTML::Entities';`. If the configuration option `decode_entities` was set to a true value, and `HTML::Entities` could be loaded, then entities will be decoded in the stripped data.

Example: given the input

```
<code> $x &lt; $y </code>
```

then stripping would produce

```
$x &lt; $y
```

and decoding the entities would make it

```
$x < $y
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for that explanation. Very thorough. Unfortunately, strip_html.c is a bit over my head, and doesn't appear to be a thing I could manipulate or emulate. So I'm still stuck with my original problem re: strip html, manipulate text, return html. Any advice in that direction?

Comment: @Nick What you are trying to do is very likely an insanely difficult problem. I'd probably write my NLP code in such a way that it works on pre-tokenized input, and will pass through whitespace tokens. Then, tag info could be kept as whitespace tokens, e.g. `<p style="..."> foo &amp; bar</p>` could be made `[p => {style => "..."}], " ", "foo", " ", "&", " ", "bar", [undef, "p"]` where array references and whitespace are treated as whitespace. This breaks down when the markup added by your processing spans across half a tag, e.g. `<p> foo & <mark>bar</p> baz</mark>`, which is invalid.

Comment: Of course, that could be mitigated by a sanitizing the output to something like `<p> foo & <mark>bar</mark></p><mark> baz</mark>`. This isn't too complex and should be doable via a simple pushdown automaton. But this may create output you do not want. Also, using special no-op tokens may not work with external libs. Have fun figuring out how to do this stuff correctly!

Comment: Tokenization is a good thought. Is there a convenient way to tokenize all words that are not within the < and > of html tags? Best I can think of is `$text="<p> foo & <mark>bar</p> baz</mark>"; $stripped=$hs->parse($text); @array1=split(/ /, $text);@array2=split(/ /, $stripped); for my $a(@array1){ for my $b(@array2) { $a=join('',$a,\^) if $a=~/$b/;}}` Now @array1 has all non-html words tokenized with the '^' symbol, and my NLProcessing can ignore non-tokenized words, and I can remove the tokens once I'm finished. Can you think of a better way?

Comment: Of course, I'd have to ensure that tags are separated from text words by spaces.

Comment: Yes, don't introduce special markers. Your data may contain `^` characters, which would make your code break. [Tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenizing) describes splitting the input into small, semantically relevant pieces and tagging them with their meaning. Perl's OO system can help with that. A simple `split` won't cut it (and will break on trivial HTML like `<br />`). I'd throw a complete HTML parser at the input, and then flatten the DOM into my tokens, while also splitting text nodes at whitespace (but keeping the whitespace). I could write a whole book on why this is hard